# Post JsonObject with Volley

Tags: android, json, parse-platform, android-volley

I'm trying to send a Post request with volley without success.

The lib is working correctly, and I manage to sent some string requests, but the Post with a JsonObject doesn't work.

```
String urlJsonReq = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore";
    String tag_json_obj = "tag_json";

    JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            urlJsonReq,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("MyApp", response.toString());
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d("MyApp", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    // hide the progress dialog
                }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("value1", "testValue1");
            params.put("value2", "testValue2");
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "xxxxxxxxxxxx");
            headers.put("X-Parse-Application-Id", "xxxxxxxxxxx");
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json";
        }
    };
```

I keep getting an error. I read somewhere, but without any details that the **volley** cannot sent JsonObjects, only receive then. That if you want to solve that problem you should implement an custom class, but I really don't know if I'm just making an stupid mistake here (it is possible).

Do you guys know something about that?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the JSONObject without overiding the getParams or getBodyContentType. Something like this for example

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    JsonObjectRequest jr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, object, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
```

Obviously you can Override the headers if you need to.